# How to write bash script to open vi and edit document?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, vim

I'd like to write a Bash script that essentially automates the following process:

1. Open the `filename.pdf` file with `vi`:

   ```
   vi filename.pdf
   ```
2. In `vi` command mode, delete lines 4-7:

   ```
   :4,7d
   ```
3. In `vi` command mode, tap <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> (capital oh) to create  a new line:

   ```
   O
   ```
4. In `vi` insert mode, type two lesser-thans and two greater-thans:

   ```
   <<>>
   ```
5. Switch `vi` to command mode:

   ```
   ESC
   ```
6. In `vi` command mode, save file and quit `vi`:

   ```
   :wq
   ```
7. Run:

   ```
   echo "Complete."
   ```

Comment: This is not a Ubuntu specific question. You should post it at the [Unix  & Linux community](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

you might want to use `ed` (which is designed to automate scripting):

```
ed < edit.sed filename.pdf
```

where `edit.sed` is:

```
4,7d
a
<<>>
.
w
q
```

This will insert `<<>>` in the fifth line.